# on click to radio button change the images

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have 3 radiobuttons,

```
 <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
            <label class="destino-label">
              <input type="radio" name="destino" value="destino" onClick="changeFormula(e)" checked>
              Cuidad</label> 
            <label class="destino-label">
           
            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="montaña" onClick="changeFormula(e)"  > Montaña </label> 
            <label class="destino-label">
            
            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa" onClick="changeFormula(e)" >Playa</label>

 <img src="./image/cuidad.jpg" name="img" id="img" alt="" width="350px" height="350px">
```

Onclick to each radiobutton I want to change the image, I am trying to do it like this, but it is not working, where do I have a error ??

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeFormula(e){
        e.stopPropagation();  
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('destino');
    var img= document.getElementsByName('img')
    if (radio[1].checked){
        img.src = "cuidad.jpg";
    }
    if (radio[2].checked){
        img.src = "mantaña.jpg";
    }
    if (radio[3].checked){
        img.src = "playa.jpg";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `var img= document.getElementsByName('img')` is returning a collection of images, even if there is only one to find, it will return a collection of one. Instead, use `var img= document.querySelector('img')` which will find the first image - not a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick

```js
    function changeFormula(e){   
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('destino');
    var img= document.getElementById('img')
    if (e==1){
/* as per image used in html the path is ./image/cuidad.jpg but in here you are using just "cuidad.jpg" try to change the path according to folder too*/
        img.src = "cuidad.jpg";
        img.alt = "cuidad.jpg";
    }else if (e==2){
        img.src = "mantaña.jpg";
                img.alt = "mantaña.jpg";

    }else if (e==3){
        img.src = "playa.jpg";
                img.alt = "playa.jpg";

    }
}
```

```html
 <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
            <label class="destino-label">
              <input type="radio" name="destino" value="destino" onClick="changeFormula(1)" checked>
              Cuidad</label> 
            <label class="destino-label">
           
            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="montaña" onClick="changeFormula(2)"  > Montaña </label> 
            <label class="destino-label">
            
            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa" onClick="changeFormula(3)" >Playa</label>

 <img src="./image/cuidad.jpg" name="img" id="img" alt="hi" width="350px" height="350px">
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a NodeList, so your desired image is the first element in that list:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeFormula(e){
        e.stopPropagation();  
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('destino');

    // Get the first item of the list:
    var img = document.getElementsByName('img')[0]

    if (radio[1].checked){
        img.src = "cuidad.jpg";
    }
    if (radio[2].checked){
        img.src = "mantaña.jpg";
    }
    if (radio[3].checked){
        img.src = "playa.jpg";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the checked radio button, and use its `value` property to get the correct image.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
function changeFormula(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // get checked radio button
    var radio = document.querySelector("input[name='destino']:checked");
    if (radio) { 
      document.querySelector('#img').src = radio.value + ".jpg";
    }
}
</script>
```

One thing I noticed is that montaña is not the same as mantaña, so either change the value of that one or rename the jpg.

Comment: thank you) i have this error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (practica.html:49:106) what i m doing wrong?

Comment: To me it looks like you changed your html from onClick="changeFormula(e)" to some number.  It should be e.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
<label class="destino-label">
  <input type="radio" name="destino" id="0" value="destino" onClick="changeFormula()" checked>
  Cuidad</label>
<label class="destino-label">

  <input type="radio" name="destino" id="1" value="montaña" onClick="changeFormula()"> Montaña </label>
<label class="destino-label">

  <input type="radio" name="destino" id="2" value="playa" onClick="changeFormula()">Playa</label>


<img src="cat.jpg" name="img" id="img" alt="" width="350px" height="350px">
<script>
  let imgs = ["cat.jpg", "dog.jpg", "dog2.jpg"]
  function changeFormula() {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    var radio = document.getElementById('n');
    var img = document.getElementById('img')
    console.log(event.target.id)
    img.src=imgs[event.target.id]

  }
</script>
```